# How to workaround bufio.Scanner.Scan exhausting an io.Reader

Tags: go, io, mocking

I have some code (see below) which tries to get the `input()` function to return each line from my `io.Reader` each time we call `input()`.

e.g.

```
input(r) == "example.com"
input(r) == "google.com"
```

> **NOTE**: The `input()` function can't be changed, as it is not under my control.

The problem is that we create a new `bufio.Scanner` instance inside the `input()` function and so the stream of bytes in my `io.Reader` gets exhausted after we call `input()` the first time, so when we call it a second time, there's no more text to return.

How can I model the `io.Reader` requirement to ensure it doesn't get exhausted completely on the first call to `input()`? I tried using an `io.LimitReader` but fundamentally that still hit the same problem of the underlying `io.Reader` type being consumed completely by the `bufio.Scanner.Scan()`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func input(r io.Reader) (string, error) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for {
        if ok := s.Scan(); !ok {
            return "", s.Err()
        }
        line := strings.TrimSpace(s.Text())
        return line, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("example.com\ngoogle.com")

    s, err := input(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("1. %+v\n", s)

    s, err = input(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("2. %+v\n", s)
}
```

I had also tried a variation where I implemented by own type and tried to reset the embedded `io.Reader` after a call to its `Read()` but this didn't work as `Read()` was called multiple times by the `bufio.Scanner.Scan()` and it wasn't possible for me to know when the scan had completed:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type MyReader struct {
    reader io.Reader
    index  int
    lines  []string
}

func (r *MyReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = r.reader.Read(p)
    r.Reset()
    return n, err
}

func (r *MyReader) Reset() {
    if r.index <= len(r.lines)-1 {
        r.reader = strings.NewReader(r.lines[r.index])
        r.index += 1
    }
}

func input(r io.Reader) (string, error) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for {
        if ok := s.Scan(); !ok {
            return "", s.Err()
        }
        line := strings.TrimSpace(s.Text())
        return line, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    r := &MyReader{
        reader: strings.NewReader("foo"),
        lines:  []string{"bar", "baz"},
    }

    s, err := input(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("1. %+v\n", s)

    s, err = input(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("2. %+v\n", s)
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is so wrong. providing a solution would make things just worse, if any solution really exists...

Comment: Re-use the same `Scanner` for each read instead of creating a new one every time.

Comment: Hi @Adrian unfortunately I'm not able to change that (it's in code outside of my control), but if I could then yes that would have been the solution.

Answer (score -1):

OK so thanks to Peter Bourgon (https://twitter.com/peterbourgon) I discovered the solution, which was to use `io.Pipe` along with some coordination in my test code to mimic the multiple inputs required...

https://play.golang.org/p/w0VPpYMytnG

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func input(r io.Reader) (string, error) {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for {
        if ok := s.Scan(); !ok {
            return "", s.Err()
        }
        line := strings.TrimSpace(s.Text())
        return line, nil
    }
}

func run(r io.Reader, w io.Writer) error {
    s, err := input(r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("first input(): %+v\n", s)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+v\n", s)

    s, err = input(r)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("second input(): %+v\n", s)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+v\n", s)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    var stdout bytes.Buffer

    stdin, prompt := io.Pipe()

    // Wait for user input and write it to the prompt
    inputc := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for input := range inputc {
            fmt.Fprintln(prompt, input)
        }
    }()

    // We need a channel so we wait for `run()` to complete
    done := make(chan bool)

    // Call `run()` and wait for response
    go func() {
        err := run(stdin, &stdout)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        done <- true
    }()

    // User provides input
    //
    // NOTE: Must provide as much input as is expected to be waited on by `run()`.
    //       For example, if `run()` calls `input()` twice, then provide two messages.
    //       Otherwise the select statement will trigger the timeout error.
    inputc <- "foo!"
    inputc <- "bar!"

    // Wait for result
    select {
    case <-done:
        fmt.Print("\ngot result!\n")
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
        fmt.Print("oh no! no result! timeout!\n")
    }

    // Inspect stdout
    fmt.Printf("\nstdout:\n%+v\n", stdout.String())
}
```

Comment: you will hav to pay your technical debt at some point. But take care to https://play.golang.org/p/OG_f8KzdDFZ

Comment: dont rely on timeouts. really. https://play.golang.org/p/YZ4xPeGx87t

Comment: check also this https://play.golang.org/p/8EPAWlZis-u

Comment: something like this https://play.golang.org/p/L8TLUm0TzPu

Comment: reuse the strings.Reader rather creating a new one https://play.golang.org/p/fO6yo1r77ym